# What does tASSOC mean?

Tags: ruby

I often get the `unexpected tASSOC` syntax error and generally know the types of errors it represents, but was wondering what `tASSOC` is and what it stands for.  Is tASSOC an acronym? Is it pronounced just like it sounds?

Comment: You should probably show the source code so someone can point out *why* you're getting an error.

Comment: I don't have any current errors, I was just wondering what a tASSOC actually is.

Comment: I think there's room for improvement in the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tASSOC` is the name of the token `=>`.

The `t`, I guess, is for "token" and `ASSOC` is to inidicate that is serves to associate a key to a value in a hash.

Borrowing from *histocrat*'s comment:

> it's pronounced like "tea association", without the "iation".

Comment: Does it stand for anything useful?

Comment: You use it to indicate key-value pairs in Hashes: `{ k1 => v1, k2 => v2 }`. Sounds like you need to review Ruby a little more.

Comment: Is tASSOC an acronym? Is it pronounced just like it sounds?

Comment: `t` is for token. `ASSOC` is for association. It associates a key to a value within a hash.

Comment: In my head, anyway, it's pronounced like "tea association" without the "iation". It's a `t`oken used to indicate an `assoc`iation between a key and a value.